# Pull a file from a docker image in Golang to local file system

Tags: docker, go

I’m trying to figure out how I can use the Go client (http://godoc.org/github.com/moby/moby/client) to pull a file from a docker image at a specific version (tag)

I want to download the image and then copy a file from the image onto the local file system. I see a lot of commands for dealing with an image, but not how to access its contents. I do see ways to access a container’s contents.

I’m suspecting I would need to download the image, create a container with the image and finally copy the contents out of the container. Though if I could avoid creating a container, that would be preferred.

Does anyone know exactly how to do this? Code snippet would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You must start the container, copy the file and then remove the container... It's not really an expensive operation since the container isn't started anyway.

Here's a working example that copies a file from the specified image to standard output.  The API is straightforward to follow:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/get-started/
- https://godoc.org/github.com/moby/moby/client

https://gist.github.com/ricardobranco777/a3be772935dfb1a183e0831496925585

```
package main

import (
        "archive/tar"
        "fmt"
        "io"
        "io/ioutil"
        "os"

        "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
        "github.com/docker/docker/api/types/container"
        "github.com/docker/docker/client"
        "golang.org/x/net/context"
)

func main() {
        if len(os.Args) != 3 {
                fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Usage: %s IMAGE FILE\n", os.Args[0])
                os.Exit(1)
        }
        imageName := os.Args[1]
        filePath := os.Args[2]

        ctx := context.Background()
        cli, err := client.NewEnvClient()
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }

        out, err := cli.ImagePull(ctx, imageName, types.ImagePullOptions{})
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
        defer out.Close()
        if _, err := ioutil.ReadAll(out); err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }

        info, err := cli.ContainerCreate(ctx, &container.Config{
                Image: imageName,
        }, nil, nil, "")
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }

        tarStream, _, err := cli.CopyFromContainer(ctx, info.ID, filePath)
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
        tr := tar.NewReader(tarStream)
        if _, err := tr.Next(); err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }

        io.Copy(os.Stdout, tr)

        if err := cli.ContainerRemove(ctx, info.ID, types.ContainerRemoveOptions{}); err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Ricardo.  I think some of the API is easy to follow, some of it isn't.  For example, the documentation lacks examples (even though they have a guide, it doesn't go very deep).  Their guide also assumes that I will use environmental variables (NewEnvClient), but I don't get the luxury.  Your example certainly helps me and now I've just got to figure out how to pull images correctly (apparently I'm doing something wrong with ref strings and connecting to the docker hub, but I'll figure it out).  Thanks!

Comment: You don't need environment variables to use the `NewEnvClient()` method.  This method just checks whether DOCKER_HOST and the TLS variables are set to get the Docker server URL, otherwise it uses the default (in the case of Linux, the Unix domain socket).

Comment: Funny enough, I realized after this comment that the host isn't the registry but the local instance (which makes sense).  Also found a bug, because if I created a NewClient() pointed at the registry and pulled an image, I get no errors either with the client or the image pull, but the image is 0B in size.  Fixed this, but now it doesn't appear as if it is is pulling the image down (though it makes my mac version of docker eat cpu like mad).

Comment: Please paste the code you used.  Maybe you've found a bug and it would be worthwhile to open an issue in Github.

Comment: I've iterated past that, but I'll go back and create a regression and paste it here.  Again, thanks for the help Ricardo, you saved me some time.

Comment: I found a bug in my own code in the pulling part.  Check again.

Comment: @RicardoBranco
why do you need this line : if _, err := ioutil.ReadAll(out); err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }

what is it achieving ?